# Please don't remove my chat notifications when I reply to one of them

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

I generally leave chat logged in during the day (which I can't imagine is any sort of corner case) and, if I pop off that tab for even just five minutes, I can easily accrue three or four notifications as people reply to some interesting thing that I said (hey, it happens occasionally…).

The problem is that when I click on the notification bubble and reply to that first message, the notification bubble then goes away and *there is no way to get it back*. Even from the StackExchange dropdown notifications box, *there is no way to find those notifications*.

Instead I have to scan the transcript manually, or instead do so using the teeth-pulling process known as Using SO Chat Search.

*Please could you keep the notifications up even when I've spoken?*

I do understand that another case is when you receive notifications whilst actively talking and you wouldn't want them accruing in that case.

So, perhaps:

**Please do not cancel chat notifications, when I've only spoken in reply to one of those notifications!**

Comment: it's the same with all notifications, the moment one is clicked it just disappears into it's own sections. Why have a '2' or '3' if clicking on one makes it '0' again